# How to export Std Dev from Raster Dataset of DEM to classify current extent and execute Contour Tool with Python?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, raster, dem, contour

I want to create Countour Lines for a DEM which are based on a "STD dev" classificaion. 
My problem is that the "Std dev" is exported in an unknown type instead of a String. So the classifacation for the Contour Tool can not be executed.

Do you have any ideas how i could convert it in a String?

**STD**

```
elevstd=arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management("rectExtract","STD")
```

**Define Variables**

```
Intervall=0  
Automatisch=0
```

**If Statements**

```
if Intervall==Automatisch and elevstd>"0" and elevstd<="5":   # Class1  
    Contour("rectExtract", "C:/fakepath/Class1.shp", 1,0)  
if Intervall==Automatisch and elevstd>"5" and elevstd<="10":  # Class2  
    Contour("rectExtract", "C:/fakepath/Class2.shp", 5,0)
```

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why, but some tools return a [Result](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/018z/018z00000046000000.htm) object instead of the actual result. From the help on [Get Raster Properties](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000m7000000):

> The Python result of this tool returns a geoprocessing Result object. In order to obtain the string value, use the Result object's getOutput method.

So you can grab the result like so, casting it to str() since it returns unicode:

```
elevstd = str(arcpy.GetRasterProperties_management("rectExtract","STD").getOutput(0))
```